# How to trigger a workflow from dev or uat or Prod Unix server by pmcmd command how to give server path and how to know server path

Tags: unix, triggers, workflow, informatica

How to trigger a workflow from UAT UNIX server from client Machine, as in client machine we cannot trigger from cmd only way is to from Unix but where can I get server path and how to trigger a particular workflow

Answer (score 0):

Infa server can be unix/linux/windows, but you can kick off any workflow from any client machine provided you have below information.

1. IntegrationServicename DomainName
2. User/Password - to kick off the workflow
3. Informatica client installed in your client machine.
4. Informatica client installation bin directory is added to PATH variable.

Once you have 1,2,3 and you complete point #4 above you are ready to connect to/run/stop/schedule any informatica workflow/s.
Here is the command you should use to kick off workflow -

```
pmcmd startworkflow -sv ​(IntegrationServicename) -d ​(DomainName) -u ​(UserName)​ -p ​(Password) ‑f ​(folderName) WorkflowName -paramfile (parameterfile)
```

If you can not change PATH, use pmcmd with its absolute path. The path in your client may be different. For my system below command will work -

```
C:\Informatica\9.6.1\clients\PowerCenterClient\CommandLineUtilities\PC\server\bin\pmcmd  startworkflow -sv ​(IntegrationServicename) -d ​(DomainName) -u ​(UserName)​ -p ​(Password) ‑f ​(folderName) WorkflowName
```

[image: Location of pmcmd command binary]

Comment: Koushik thanks,
but my doubt was how can I give path of Informatica installed path in Unix server
both are different right !
if there is a way to give please help me how to connect

if server is installed in same machine i can go to command prompt and give path of c:/informatica/10.2/server/bin/ where pmcmd file is there and run the pmcmd 

but as client machine i have only client and also i think we can run from only unix either UAT,PROD,DEV 
where to go after logging into uat server to give pmcmd

Comment: thats what i mentioned above. every client machine has pmcmd command inside bin folder. Typically pmcmd is kept at `<<infa install directory>>\clients\PowerCenterClient\CommandLineUtilities\PC\server\bin` folder. In my system its in `C:\Informatica\9.6.1\clients\PowerCenterClient\CommandLineUtilities\PC\server\bin`

Comment: got it Koushik,
Thank you so much

Comment: did it work? is your issue resolved?

Comment: not actually, i have gone to command prompt and give cd c:informatica\10.2.0\\clients\PowerCenterClient\CommandLineUtilities\PC\server\bin and pmcmd startworkflow -sv INFA_INT -d Domain -u Administrator -p Administrator -f TRAINING_ wf_m_EMP_LKP_SCD2_S_T it shown a error of ''no gate way connectivity provided for domain'' it will be very help full if you connect mailid:chinnarajuvudimudi@gmail.com

Comment: You need to get correct domain and service info from infa admin.